# C : uninitialized char pointer and print out the address

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I have some local pointers and before which
I am given two global pointers.

My task is to print out every byte between the two global pointers +/- 32.
And the local pointers will be different because I will mark it different than global pointers.

And my question is how to initialize at first every byte between the two pointers?
The following is my try but not working:

```
// global scope
char * minimum_ptr, * maximum_ptr;

int main()
// inside main function
char * temp_ptr = minimum_ptr-32;
char * add_ptr = minimum_ptr-32;
while (temp_ptr != maximum_ptr+32) {
  add_ptr = NULL;
  temp_ptr++;
}

// getting errors
printf("%p", (char *)(minimum_ptr));
printf("%p", (char *)(minimum_ptr+1));
```

I corrected it, but still confusing sorry. I am confused too. All I want, is to print out the address between the two pointers, minimum_ptr-32 and maximum_ptr+32, and minimum_ptr and maximum_ptr are not initialized yet but I might need so if I need to.

Addition:
I want to initialize all of them first and do some assignment after then so that I can print out everything between and see what and where has been assigned. Thanks

Comment: Besides that this whole idea is weird, why do you set `temp_ptr` to `NULL` and then to 1 (`temp_ptr++;`)?

Comment: Yes right, I messed it up. Let me think

Comment: I corrected it, but still confusing sorry. I am confused too. All I want, is to print out the address between the two pointers, minimum_ptr-32 and maximum_ptr+32, and minimum_ptr and maximum_ptr are not initialized yet but I might need so if I need to.

Comment: Where are you initializing the global pointers, and allocating the memory between them (and +/- 32 bytes)? Until you do that you will have undefined behavior.

Comment: I want to initialize all of them first and do some assignment after then so that I can print out everything between and see what and where has been assigned. Thanks

Comment: @KeenanERNLDKNF Then why don't you do so? I. e. why don't you just... **go ahead and initialize them before printing?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to be sure that the pointers are showing the correct addresses. Pointers are not different then arrays (yes they are different but..), so you may assume them to be arrays. I assume that the maximum_ptr's address is greater than the minimum_ptr's address.

```
uint dist = maximum_ptr - minimum_ptr;
for (int i = 0; i < dist; ++i) {
   minimum_ptr[i] = 'A';
}
```

or you might use std::fill

```
std::fill(minimum_ptr, maximum_ptr, 'a');
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/

you might adjust the pointer values

```
std::fill(minimum_ptr - 32, maximum_ptr + 32, 'a');
```

Comment: `std::fill()` is a C++ function.

Comment: do we have same function for C? fill looks very useful but I need C function. Thanks

Comment: memset(min_ptr-16, 'A', 32); I tried this but not working. Any alternative?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/ If you type it like in this webpage, does it work? First of all try printing the memory area between min_ptr and max_ptr, then try to introduce -16 etc. You might be going out of scope. printf("%p" => this is used to write addresses, you need printf("%d", min_ptr[i]); http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/